# Generar condición en consultas mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php7, condiciones

Estoy recibiendo una variable por get al presionar un botón y esta variable es un dato almacenado en mysql, dicha variable se tiene que proyectar en una consulta dependiendo de su alojamiento. Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que con una condicional me ejecute una consulta u otra? **Es decir, si el pin pertenece a una tabla que ejecute una consulta o si pertenece a otra tabla dentro de la misma BD que ejecute otra**.

Este es mi código:

Código del botón que envía el valor del pin de la tabla "empresas registradas"

```
 <?php echo "<td><form action='reportesPDF.php?pin=".$row['pin']."' method='POST'> <button type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='generate_pdf' title='Reportes Cuestionarios-50'><i class='far fa-file-pdf' color='white'></i></button></form></td>";?>
```

reportesPDF.php (**puede generar el pdf de una tabla o de otra dependiente el pin enviado y a que tabla pertenece, ya que puede estar en dos**)

```
<?php  
 $pin_variable = $_GET['pin'];
 function fetch_data()  
 {  
 $output = '';  
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydbname"); 
  $conn -> set_charset("utf8"); 
  $sql = "SELECT * tabla1 T INNER JOIN empresasregistradas E ON T.pin = E.pin WHERE T.pin ='{$_GET['pin']}' ORDER BY T.pin ASC";  
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
     CÓDIGO PARA IMPRIMIR PDF DE LOS DATOS
  }

<?
```

Si `$pin_variable = $_GET['pin'];` perteneciera a otra tabla, tendría que hacer la consulta de esa tabla, es decir:

`$sqlDos = "SELECT * tabla2 T INNER JOIN empresasregistradas E ON T.pin = E.pin WHERE T.pin ='{$_GET['pin']}' ORDER BY T.pin ASC";`

Comment: Hablando de valores, ¿cuál es el valor de $pin_variable que indicaría hacer una acción u otra?

Comment: Tendrías que hacer dos consultas por separado

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que hay en `$_GET['pin']`, el nombre de la tabla o bien otra cosa? Hablas de una u otra consulta, ¿podrías mostrar cómo tienen que ser esas consultas y en base a qué se tiene que decidir ejecutar una u otra?

Comment: @A. Cedano ```$_GET['pin']``` es un pin recibido de una tabla de registros dicha tabla contiene ese campo pin, otras dos tablas tambien tienen ese campo pin y por ende comparten los mismos datos.

Comment: @SalvaCastro estaba pensando en ello pero no se como incluirlas en el la condición.

Comment: Entiendo eso. Pero según tú hay una decisión a tomar: *¿envío la consulta a la `TablaA` o a la `TablaB`?* entonces, ¿en base a qué criterio se decide qué consulta enviar? ¿cómo es cada consulta, sólo cambia el nombre de la tabla o hay otras cosas que cambian en ella? Eso es fundamental para responder a tu pregunta, pero no lo explicas con claridad. Además,  ¿por qué no envías con el `$_GET` también el nombre de la tabla a la cual se debe consultar?

Comment: Hay otros para metros de la tabla que se tienen que considerar @A.Cedano he editado mi pregunta esperando pueda ser más clara. Lo único que quiero es que con un sólo botón pueda generar el pdf con ayuda de una consulta o de otra ya que puede ser una ```tabla A``` o ```tabla B según``` el ```PIN``` de la tabla donde se encuentre alojado.

Comment: No entiendo mucho. O sea, ¿lo que determina la tabla a la que hay que consultar es  el dato que hay en el pin? Si es así, no sería mejor hacer un JOIN o algo así. Es que me parece muy rara la lógica que estás implementando o hay algo que se me escapa.

Comment: @A. Cedano Si el ```PIN``` envíado por Get se encuentra en ```Tabla A```, ejecutar ```consulta1```. Si el ```PIN``` envíado por Get se encuentra en ```Tabla B```, ejecutar ```consulta2```.

Comment: Esa es precisamente la lógica que no entiendo. Significa que habría que consultar a dos tablas para buscar si el pin está en una o en otra ... No es que sea imposible, pero me parece extraño como lógica. De todos modos, si tiene que ser así, entonces tienes que hacer una consulta a la `TablaA` a ver si el pin está ahí, si está, entonces lanzas la consulta respectiva y si no está, te vas a buscar a la `TablaB` y si está, lanzas la consulta respectiva. Y si no está en ninguna pues haces lo que haya que hacer en ese caso. De todos modos, repito, me parece complicado como lógica.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103632/discussion-between-marianakiabeth-and-a-cedano).